# Custom CSS Strikethrough

Tags: html, css, border

I am creating a web app in which I want to show 2 prices:

- Price 1 should be the actual price.
- Price 2 should be the discounted price.

Now I want to show price 1 as canceled, similar to the image below, but don't know which CSS property to use for this:

[image: This]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put a diagonal line over a textbox in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392219/how-to-put-a-diagonal-line-over-a-textbox-in-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is some basic CSS to make your desired strike. In this case, you can add the `cross` class to the old price.

```css
.cross {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.cross::before, .cross::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
.cross::before {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-10deg);
    transform: skewY(-10deg);
}
.cross::after {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(10deg);
    transform: skewY(10deg);
}
```

```html
<p>$9.99</p>
<p class="cross">$19.99</p>
```

Source: [This page](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/09/12/building-custom-text-strikethroughs-with-css/) explains further strikes.